# When I jump from one page to the next on my site it exposes the HTML in Chrome

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have categories within my site. The HTML is exposed for a split second when I go from one category to the next. FYI I'm using Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html></html>
<head>
<title>Dating Catalog</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to "Dating Catalog", root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <!-- lists and links all categories on the top of home page -->
        <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
        <li class="category-link">
      <%= link_to category.name, resources_path(category: category.name) %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
 <%= yield %>
</div>
```

Comment: Make sure you have a closing div tag for the container div after the yield block.

Comment: you have '</html>' closed right at the top after the open '<html>' you also never added '</body></html>' to the very end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that:

- HTML tags like `<body>`, `<div>` are properly closed with `</body>`, `</div>`.
- `<head>...</head>` and `<body>...</body>` are wrapped inside of `<html>...</html>`.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- ... -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <!-- ... -->
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <%= yield %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```